# jQuery adding new properties to JavaScript DOM Object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here are two blocks of codes, one with JavaSript, the second one is in jQuery. At the end of each code I'm adding new properties (**x** and **y**) to the JavaScript Object **div**

But the properties are being saved on the first example with JavaScript, but jQuery seems not to be working as supposed to be.

Question: Is there any specific way of adding new properties to the JavaScript DOM object?

**JavaScript**

```
  init = function() {
                var puzzleArea = document.getElementById('puzzlearea');
                var divs = puzzleArea.getElementsByTagName("div");

                // initialize each piece
                for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
                    var div = divs[i];

                    // calculate x and y for this piece
                    var x = ((i % 4) * 100);
                    var y = (Math.floor(i / 4) * 100);

                    // set basic style and background
                    div.className = "puzzlepiece";
                    div.style.left = x + 'px';
                    div.style.top = y + 'px';
                    div.style.backgroundImage = 'url("background.jpg")';
                    div.style.backgroundPosition = -x + 'px ' + (-y) + 'px';

                    // store x and y for later
                    div.x = x;
                    div.y = y;
                }
            };
```

**jQuery**

```
init = function() {
    var puzzleArea = $('div#puzzlearea');
    var divs = $('div#puzzlearea div');
    divs.each(function(idx, e) {
        var x = ((idx % 4) * 100);
        var y = (Math.floor(idx / 4) * 100);
        $(this).addClass("puzzlepiece").css({
            "left":x + "px",
            "top":y + "px",
            "background-image":"url('background.jpg')",
            "background-position":-x + "px " + (-y) + "px"});
        $(this).x = x;
        $(this).y = y;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

When you add property to jquery object it doesn't get added to DOM element. It just gets added to the object and gets destroyed with the object later. You can use data api of jquery  to place the values in the cache instead.

```
    $(this).data('x', x); //or do this.x = x;
    $(this).data('y', y); //or do this.y = y
```

or just save as

```
    $(this).data('coords', {"x":x, "y": y});
```

and retrieve using the getter:

```
    var coords = $(this).data('coords');
```

Comment: I tried this one, but it didn't give the expected result. prop() method is looking good

Comment: if `div.x = x` works for you then `this.x` should also work. Also i am not sure if it is a good idea to pollute the element by adding properties to it other than what it has. (I am not sure but proabably it may cause memory leaks). Best way is to use `data-*` attribute according to me which is legally valid as well.

Answer (score 2):

To do the same thing using jQuery you would use the `prop` method:

```
$(this).prop('x', x);
$(this).prop('y', y);
```